# métrica para trazer visitas por dia google-analytics

Tags: google-analytics-api

Alguém conhece alguma métrica ou dimensão do google analytics que dado um periodo de data, ele traga número de acessos por cada dia desse período?
Exemplo:

```
dateRanges: [
          {
            startDate: '23-11-2017',
            endDate: '25-11-2017'
          }
        ],
        metrics: [
          {
            expression: 'ga:UsuariosPorDia'
          }
```

Resposta:

"2017-11-23" : 25,
"2017-11-24" :50,
"2017-11-25"

Answer (score 0):

Consegui o que eu precisava, adicionando o parametro "ga:date" no dimensions.

Exemplo:

```
 metrics: [
          {
            expression:'ga:users'
          },

        ],
        dimensions: [
        {
          name: "ga:date"
        }]
```